# How can I add a JTree in an arrayList in java?

Tags: java

the code that I have I started it with a class.

```
ublic class GeneradorDOM {


public String tagRoot;
public ArrayList<GeneradorDOM> al_hijosDhijos;

public GeneradorDOM(String tagRoot) {
    this.tagRoot = tagRoot;
    al_hijosDhijos = new ArrayList<>();
}}
```

This is the other code where I add the children of the first children, the error is that it repeats the children every time I add a new one. Could you help me avoid repetition or with another better code using recursion?

```
public void add2ndChild(DefaultTreeModel mdelTree, DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    for (int c = 0; c < mdelTree.getChildCount(mdelTree.getRoot()); c++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mdelTree.getChildCount(mdelTree.getChild(mdelTree.getRoot(), c)); i++) {

            if (node.toString().equals(mdelTree.getChild(mdelTree.getRoot(), c).toString())) {
                for (int j = 0; j < al_hijosDhijos.size(); j++) {
                    if (al_hijosDhijos.get(j).tagRoot.equals(node.toString())) {
                     al_hijosDhijos.get(j).al_hijosDhijos.add(new GeneradorDOM(mdelTree.getChild(mdelTree.getChild(mdelTree.getRoot(), c), i).toString()));                 
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note: `node.toString().equals(mdelTree.getChild(mdelTree.getRoot(), c).toString())` seems odd. I'd would most likely be better to use `node.equals(child)`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what exactly you're trying to do. Could you provide some example (like a simple tree and how it should change)?

Comment: jtree:root  -color *green*blue -sport *soccer                                                                                                                             I have only added the root and the two colors of the children and the sports within the arraylist, but when I add several children to the sport or the colors, I repeat them in the arraylist. What I do not know is how to eliminate that or if they have some other better code of how to add a jtree in an arraylist using recursion.

Comment: With example I meant something more thorough, e.g. some initial data representing the tree (ideally visualized) and how that should change. Generally your code is hard to understand and seems to be unnecessarily complex. You'd normally identify the node to add the child to first (that should easily be done recursively) and _then_ you just add the node. Do that in two steps instead of one. If you're having problems using recursion in general you should read up on it.

Comment: Generally I have the feeling that you're quite new to programming. If that's the case you seem to make quite a common mistake: you're diving right into UI development without having a firm grasp of the basics first - which encompasses recursion, using debugger etc. - doing so is like trying to ride a bike for the first time without any safety measures, you're very likely to get hurt and frustrated with all the little pitfalls that wait along the way.